# Menu object from list of IContributionItem

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to create `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu`object from the list of `org.eclipse.jface.action.ContributionItem`. I have followed the below way but it is returning me the null.

```
MenuManager m = new MenuManager();
m.add(contributionitem1);
m.add(contributionitem2);
....
....
m.add(contributionitem9);
```

and i have called

```
m.getMenu();
```

which is returning me null. Any pointers will help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is returning null because the menu is being created. You need to create it first, take a look at this method from MenuManager, you need to pass in a SWT control to actually create a menu.

```java
  public Menu createMenuBar(Decorations parent) {
    if (!menuExist()) {
        menu = new Menu(parent, SWT.BAR);
        menu.setData(MANAGER_KEY, this);
        update(false);
    }
    return menu;
}
```